# Right outer join & inner join in SQL - convert to linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a SQL query and I need to convert it to a linq query - but I can't convert it properly.

Here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    dbo.AlarmKodlari.AlarmKodu, dbo.AlarmKodlari.Tanimi
FROM   
    dbo.AlarmKodlari 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN               
    dbo.Hestipdetay ON dbo.AlarmKodlari.AlarmKodu = dbo.Hestipdetay.RaporTanimi 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Partitions 
INNER JOIN                                                                      
    dbo.Musteriler ON dbo.Partitions.MustKod = dbo.Musteriler.MustKod 
INNER JOIN                      
    dbo.HesTipleri ON dbo.Musteriler.MustTipi = dbo.HesTipleri.TipKodu 
    ON dbo.Hestipdetay.TipKodu = dbo.HesTipleri.TipKodu
WHERE 
    (dbo.hestipdetay.raportipi = 4) 
    AND (dbo.Partitions.AboneNo = 399)
```

Comment: I'd start with rearranging the JOIN/ON clauses, to make things clearer.

Comment: I actually stuck with last inner join which there are two on here. And also dont know how to convert all query

Comment: what have you got so far?  Are you saying you've joined all but the last table?

Comment: yes, I can't join that part. In the last inner join ON dbo.Hestipdetay.TipKodu = dbo.HesTipleri.TipKodu. There are two on operation, linq dont allow to use two on in the same join

Comment: Actually LINQ does allow that. Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.